# Unattended linux installation (Debian/Ubuntu)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, system-installation

I want to make an Debian or Ubuntu unattended ISO, for my FOG server - to boot up system installation via LAN. I've searched over the internet but I didn't found nothing, which will be adequate for me.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an unattended Ubuntu install consists of the following steps:

1. Create a configuration file, ks.cfg, using the GUI Kickstart tool.
2. Extract the files from the Ubuntu install ISO.
3. Add the ks.cfg file to the install disk and alter the boot menu to add automatic install as an install option.
4. Reconstitute the ISO file.

See http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/unattended-ubuntu-installations for more details.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation/

This project provides all you need to create an unattended installation of a minimal setup of Linux, whereas minimal translates to the most lightweight setup - including an OpenSSH service and Python - which you can derive from the standard installer of a Linux distribution. The idea is, you will do all further deployment of your configurations and services with the help of Ansible or similar tools once you completed the minimal setup.

Comment: Niklas, if this is your project your really need to disclose that.